# Return key & value of property in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects each object has some properties. how can i return only one property from all the object the key and the value together in an array?

Right now I'm only getting the values

This returns an array of objects:

```
var columnWidth = $('#grid').data('gridData').columns;
```

This return an array of values of a property named width from each object:

```
columnWidth.map(function(e) {return e.width;});
```

Now what im getting back is this:

```
[30, 50, 80, 80, 90, 125]
```

What I want to get back is:

```
["Width":30, "Width":50, "Width":80, "Width":80, "Width":90, "Width":125]
```

Comment: The format you're trying to create is not valid javascript; you cannot have named items in an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then just return those objects:

```
columnWidth.map(function(e) {return { width: e.width }; } );
```

That'll give you an array that looks like

```
[ { width: 30 }, { width: 50 }, ... ]
```

(Use `Width: e.width` if you want the property name capitalized.)

The format described in your question is not meaningful; there's no JavaScript data structure that looks like that, as array indexes are numeric. If you want a different structure, you may be able to do it with `.map()` or with `.reduce()`.

This solution gives you an array of objects, each of which has a single property named "width". That seems like the closest approximation to your stated goal.

Comment: dont you think it should be `return { "Width" : e.width }; }` and the return will be array of objects  :) :)

Comment: @bipen oh OK if the property name should be capitalized. It does not need to be quoted however.